# Why am I receiving this error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Issue:** I am receiving error (listed below) when i try to save form data from one controller to another.

> StripeAccount(#473341532384680) expected, got "acct_7424613FLPIHiXZ"
>   which is an instance of String(#47334237953540)

**Question:** What in my code is creating the error?

I have form input that works but I want to take some of the data from it and append it elsewhere to a separate controller.

The form is for users and stripe_account controller.  I want to take the acct.id from the stripe_account and also save it in the @user table under stripe_account.

User Model:

```
  has_one :stripe_account
```

Stripe_account Model:

```
  belongs_to :users
```

Controller Stripe_account:

```
 def new
        @stripe_account = StripeAccount.new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])

      end

    def create

        @stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @stripe_account.user_id = current_user.id
          acct = Stripe::Account.create({
.....
.....
    @stripe_account.acct_id = acct.id
#below is what isn't working
    @user.stripe_account = acct.id

  respond_to do |format|
      if @stripe_account.save!
        format.html { redirect_to new_bank_account_path, notice: 'Stripe account was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stripe_account }


      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stripe_account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

View:

```
  <%= form_for ([@user, @stripe_account]) do | f | %>
```

Routes:

```
resources :users do
    resources :stripe_accounts
  end
```

but got the error: StripeAccount(#473341532384680) expected, got "acct_7424613FLPIHiXZ" which is an instance of String(#47334237953540)

... In the Users schema, I have "stripe_account" set as a string.

I tried

```
acct_id = current_user.stripe_account
```

and other iterations of this.  I am assuming the issue is in my model so i tried:
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :stripe_account
but the same error appeared.

Comment: So what is the line `@user.stripe_account = acct.id` for? You already bind an user to stripe account. Also, the direct source of error is pretty obvious, if you use `@user.stripe_account=` method, it expect `StripeAccount` instance.

Comment: It's to store it for use later on to update, edit, pay, etc.  You're right though, I'm not exactly sure I should be going this far in doing this.  I have a stripe_account table and a User table separate.  The Stripe account takes into account the user_id, so i know what user belongs to what stripe_account.  But i also want to cross through the acct.id under the User table as well under stripe_account as my other tables/models/controllers are connected through User mostly.  What do you think, is that too far?

Comment: if you use @user.stripe_account= method, it expect StripeAccount instance --- so are you saying I should be doing something more like @user.user.stripe_account? or what?

Comment: @user.user.stripe_account didn't work.  is there a way i can save the acct.id to the current users user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone comes across this.  I had issues recording data from form to 2 controllers tables.

This is what i did to fix it (thanks to a stackO user) @arieljuod

```
replacing:
  # @stripe_account = StripeAccount.new(stripe_account_params)
    # @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    # @stripe_account.user_id = current_user.id
with:
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @stripe_account = @user.build_stripe_account(stripe_account_params)

//and then saving from this://
    if @stripe_account.save!
//to this://
    if @stripe_account.save! && @user.save
```